# Two Copies of data are inputted in mysql

Tags: android, mysql

My android application successfully inputs data from the adroid to the database through the server but it saves two copies of data. It shouldnt be like that. what is wrong?

Comment: What is wrong? => Without knowing what you have tried and implemented, we can't be magician!

Comment: [RELATED QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225652/input-data-from-android-to-database-in-mysql)